# ffmpeg "Invalid length 0x59f0 > 0x8bd7fe90 in parent" when trying to do anything with mkv files

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I don't think I've ever had this problem prior to one or two months ago. At first I thought I was entering the wrong commands or feeding it corrupted files, but this happens with every single mkv file I've tried (which are coming from different sources). Example:

```
PS O:\video_editing\ff> ffmpeg -i '.\Six Shooter (2004) 1080p.bluray.x264-hd4u[N1C].mkv'
ffmpeg version N-93286-g4635f64953 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.102 / 58. 47.102
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '.\Six Shooter (2004) 1080p.bluray.x264-hd4u[N1C].mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.5 + libmatroska v1.4.8
    creation_time   : 2018-02-18T09:08:01.000000Z
  Duration: 00:26:30.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11797 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 569.567000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Chapter #0:1: start 569.567000, end 1246.452000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Chapter #0:2: start 1246.452000, end 1590.976000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1064, SAR 1:1 DAR 240:133, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 11571497
      BPS-eng         : 11571497
      DURATION        : 00:26:30.965000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:30.965000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 38145
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 38145
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 2301230881
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2301230881
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English AC3 224 kbps
      BPS             : 224000
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION        : 00:26:30.976000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:30.976000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 49718
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 49718
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 44547328
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 44547328
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : English SDH
      BPS             : 54
      BPS-eng         : 54
      DURATION        : 00:25:29.694000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:25:29.694000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 309
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 309
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 10462
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10462
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(pol): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : Polish
      BPS             : 49
      BPS-eng         : 49
      DURATION        : 00:26:06.772000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:06.772000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 297
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 297
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 9701
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 9701
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
At least one output file must be specified
PS O:\video_editing\ff> ffmpeg -i '.\Six Shooter (2004) 1080p.bluray.x264-hd4u[N1C].mkv' -c copy '.\Six Shooter (2004) 1080p.bluray.x264-hd4u[N1C]_copy.mkv'
ffmpeg version N-93286-g4635f64953 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.102 / 58. 47.102
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '.\Six Shooter (2004) 1080p.bluray.x264-hd4u[N1C].mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.5 + libmatroska v1.4.8
    creation_time   : 2018-02-18T09:08:01.000000Z
  Duration: 00:26:30.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11797 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 569.567000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Chapter #0:1: start 569.567000, end 1246.452000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Chapter #0:2: start 1246.452000, end 1590.976000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1064, SAR 1:1 DAR 240:133, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 11571497
      BPS-eng         : 11571497
      DURATION        : 00:26:30.965000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:30.965000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 38145
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 38145
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 2301230881
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2301230881
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English AC3 224 kbps
      BPS             : 224000
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION        : 00:26:30.976000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:30.976000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 49718
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 49718
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 44547328
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 44547328
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : English SDH
      BPS             : 54
      BPS-eng         : 54
      DURATION        : 00:25:29.694000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:25:29.694000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 309
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 309
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 10462
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10462
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(pol): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : Polish
      BPS             : 49
      BPS-eng         : 49
      DURATION        : 00:26:06.772000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:06.772000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 297
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 297
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 9701
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 9701
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Output #0, matroska, to '.\Six Shooter (2004) 1080p.bluray.x264-hd4u[N1C]_copy.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.101
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 569.567000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Chapter #0:1: start 569.567000, end 1246.452000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Chapter #0:2: start 1246.452000, end 1590.976000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1064 [SAR 1:1 DAR 240:133], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 11571497
      BPS-eng         : 11571497
      DURATION        : 00:26:30.965000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:30.965000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 38145
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 38145
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 2301230881
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2301230881
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English AC3 224 kbps
      BPS             : 224000
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION        : 00:26:30.976000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:26:30.976000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 49718
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 49718
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 44547328
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 44547328
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : English SDH
      BPS             : 54
      BPS-eng         : 54
      DURATION        : 00:25:29.694000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:25:29.694000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 309
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 309
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 10462
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10462
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-02-18 09:08:01
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 3162 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=  129560kB time=00:02:11.96 bitrate=8042.5kbits/s speed= 26frame= 5609 fps=5604 q=-1.0 size=  266189kB time=00:03:54.11 bitrate=9314.4kbits/s speed= 2frame= 7606 fps=5060 q=-1.0 size=  398518kB time=00:05:17.34 bitrate=10287.4kbits/s speed= frame= 9716 fps=4841 q=-1.0 size=  531397kB time=00:06:45.37 bitrate=10738.7kbits/s speed= frame=12088 fps=4805 q=-1.0 size=  665217kB time=00:08:24.19 bitrate=10808.3kbits/s speed=2frame=14237 fps=4721 q=-1.0 size=  795989kB time=00:09:53.72 bitrate=10982.7kbits/s speed= frame=16151 fps=4590 q=-1.0 size=  921736kB time=00:11:13.76 bitrate=11207.0kbits/s speed= frame=18371 fps=4571 q=-1.0 size= 1050391kB time=00:12:46.30 bitrate=11229.0kbits/s speed= frame=19822 fps=4357 q=-1.0 size= 1167313kB time=00:13:46.78 bitrate=11566.1kbits/s speed= frame=22293 fps=4414 q=-1.0 size= 1305211kB time=00:15:29.82 bitrate=11499.3kbits/s speed= frame=24584 fps=4422 q=-1.0 size= 1461000kB time=00:17:05.50 bitrate=11670.9kbits/s speed= frame=26677 fps=4391 q=-1.0 size= 1617073kB time=00:18:32.73 bitrate=11904.9kbits/s speed= frame=28500 fps=4332 q=-1.0 size= 1760880kB time=00:19:48.76 bitrate=12134.5kbits/s speed= frame=30490 fps=4305 q=-1.0 size= 1902637kB time=00:21:11.80 bitrate=12255.3kbits/s speed= frame=33042 fps=4358 q=-1.0 size= 2047984kB time=00:22:58.20 bitrate=12173.1kbits/s speed= frame=35874 fps=4429 q=-1.0 size= 2203686kB time=00:24:56.38 bitrate=12064.1kbits/s speed= [matroska,webm @ 000001bef8528a80] Invalid length 0x59f0 > 0x8bd7fe90 in parent
frame=38145 fps=4541 q=-1.0 Lsize= 2291479kB time=00:26:30.94 bitrate=11799.2kbits/s speed= 189x
video:2247296kB audio:43503kB subtitle:10kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.029226%
```

Not only did it seemingly start re-encoding when it shouldn't, it gives the error from the title at the end, and the resultant file has a different size. Now that's just copying. Same container, same everything. When I try remapping streams, re-encoding the audio tracks or changing containers things get worse. I don't know if it's the recent ffmpeg releases having this bug or my Windows install giving up. As I said, just a few months ago everything was working.

It's also worth noting that mp4 files work just fine.

Comment: The message was introduced in [avformat/matroskadec: Check parents remaining length](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=9326117bf63b04a466d9e787224e56ba8cdbb21).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue today. I was able to get around it by using `mkclean` from https://www.matroska.org/downloads/mkclean.html.

It's a command-line tool provided by Matroska (the development group responsible for the mkv container format). I was able to fix my file by just running `./mkclean <input video file.mkv> <output video file.mkv>`

I can confirm that older versions of ffmpeg don't seem to run into this hiccup. On another machine, I have an older version of ffmpeg (3.4.2, compiled with homebrew on Mac OS) that handled the mkv file just fine. Also just out of curiosity, I built ffmpeg from the latest source with the default configuration, and it too gave me a "Invalid length 0x15d6 > 0xfa3525f in parent" error.

Comment: It worked! I wonder why the older versions didn't have the issue. Or maybe they did and just didn't report it. One interesting thing is that, even though ffmpeg works just fine with the fixed mkv and produces second mkv without errors, if I try to use ffmpeg again on that second mkv, I get the 'invalid length" error once again.

Comment: It looks like this error message was added just a few weeks ago ( https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/9326117bf63b04a466d9e787224e56ba8cdbb215 ), and isn't part of a stable release yet. So I think, the easiest thing to do might just be to try using the latest stable release (4.1.1 right now).

Comment: Would be nice to get some instructions on getting that source tarball to compile, since it apparently depends on something called `coremake` but doesn't come with it. I had to build the entire suite https://github.com/Matroska-Org/foundation-source